# Take wired internet from a Poe access point

Tags: cisco, access-point

how can i take wired internet from the access point?[image]

Comment: Put a "dumb" switch between the link in the switch and the power injector, assuming no port-security, 802.1X or mac address filtering has been configured on the intelligent switch.

Comment: i'm 90 meters away from the switch,i want from the access point

Comment: Then i don't see much of a possibility unless you can disconnect the power injector and connect the wire from the AP directly to the switch and buy a PoE switch, connect that to the end of the AP wire and connect the AP to the PoE switch.

Comment: can the second poe switch supply with power the access point?

Comment: Of course there are plenty of small compact office switches with PoE capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnecting and adding a PoE capable compact switch at the AP location 90 meters from the switch could be a solution. Then connecting the AP to the compact switch which then will hold the uplink gives the possibility to add more hosts at the AP location. This solution is based on the fact, that no port-security, 802.1X or mac address filtering has been configured on the intelligent switch.

Diagram for your eyes:
[image]

Comment: There are small switches that are powered by POE and let POE still go to your AP. You can find them on most sites.You may need your POE adapter to be POE plus (check the documentation that comes with your POE powered switch) but that's your best option if you don't want to run power to a switch local to the AP or another cable from your "main" switch.

Comment: Sounds like something i would never use.

Comment: Personally, I'd pull two cables and use the old one as a pull cord. Just offering an alternative option.